# Is there a way in Firefox Developer Edition to always start with DevTools open?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools

I use Firefox Developer Edition for all my development. But I would like DevTools to always be open when I start Firefox. Is there any way to do that? I know I can just hit F12 but it would be a nice feature.

Comment: Do any of these work? https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/CommandLineOptions#Other_components

Comment: @GeneralGrievance I tried "firefox -devtools" but it didn't work. Am I missing another option? Maybe a boolean flag...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I probably should have clarified a bit more...

What I was really trying to do was to get Visual Studio 2022 to automatically open Firefox DevEd with the DevTools open when I began debugging my VS project.

By default, VS will automatically open your chosen browser when debugging. However the Debug profile does not include a way to send the "-devtools" option to Firefox. (Or if it does, I couldn't find it.)

So I unchecked the "Launch Browser" setting in the Debug profile...
[image]

...and added "-devtools" to the Target item in the Firefox Properties panel.
[image]

So now when I debug my project, I just Run it then manually open Firefox. And it still supports Hot Reload if you have that enabled. This works pretty well but it would still be nice if you could send options/flags to your chosen browser. But this will work for now!